# Submit / Goto when focused in input and press enter

Tags: jquery, submit, goto, enter

I'm not sure why this isn't working? I've tried a couple methods and looked around, but none of the examples work for me. My code:

HTML

```
<div id='SearchBar'>

    <form id='SearchBar'>

        <input placeholder='Search' id='SearchBar'></input>

    </form>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#SearchBar{
                background:#ffffff;
                width:224px;
                height:32px;
                float:right;
            }

                form#SearchBar {
                    width:100%;
                    height:100%;
                }

                    input#SearchBar {   
                        font-size:16px;
                        border:none;
                        width:208px;
                        height:32px;
                        padding:0 8px;
                    }

                        input#SearchBar:focus{
                            outline-color:#2c5aa0;
                        }
```

jQuery

```
$('input#SearchBar').keypress(function(event) {

    if (event.which == 13) {

              window.location = list.html; //or submit or do whatever

    }

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `keyup` event and you are missing quotation marks for `list.html`, `list` object is `undefined` so it doesn't have `html` property!

```
$(function(){
    $('#SearchBar').keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            window.location.href = 'list.html'; 
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I am not sure why but that still doesn't work for me... Let me add my HTML and maybe that will help?

Comment: @jstacks IDs must be unique, jQuery only selects the first element with that specific ID.